# TwinColSearch with Textfield search

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin7

I'm trying to set up two TextFields to be able to search each column of a TwinColSearch, in Vaadin7.
Is there any working solution for that?

Comment: Do you mean the TwinColSelect component? For this, it's not possible to filter by some text fields. You will have to implement it yourself with two select boxes and the corresponding text fields.

Comment: Thanks, I have did that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if i understood you right, but maybe a [grid](https://vaadin.com/grid) is a better option for you? Within a grid you can filter each column, see the example.

Comment: Thanks for your help.I figured out it's impossible to reach as I want it.